# TypeError: unsupported format string passed to NoneType.__format__ for a raspberry project in python

Tags: python

```
   hello,
    I have a DHT22 that turn on/off some GPIOs depending of my temperature.
    The problem is that when i reach 25 degrees, my script crashes and I receive this error:

TypeError: unsupported format string passed to NoneType.__format__
```

about this line:
print ("Temp={0:0.1f}*C humidity={1:0.1f}%".format(temperature, humidity));

Can anyone help me about this ? i can't fix it. I've been trying for so long...
Thank you very much

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time
import Adafruit_DHT

DHT_sensor = Adafruit_DHT.DHT22
DHT_PIN = 4

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setwarnings(False)
GPIO.setup(18,GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(21,GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(23,GPIO.OUT)

while True:
    time.sleep(3),
    humidity, temperature  = Adafruit_DHT.read_retry(DHT_sensor, DHT_PIN)
    print ("Temp={0:0.1f}*C humidity={1:0.1f}%".format(temperature, humidity));
    if temperature > 25:
       print ("vanne ouverte")
       print ("boiler en fonctionnement")
       print ("ventilateur désactivé")
       print ("circulateur en fonctionnement")
       GPIO.output(18,GPIO.HIGH)
       GPIO.output(21,GPIO.HIGH)
       GPIO.output(23,GPIO.HIGH)

    else:
       print ("vanne fermée")
       print ("boiler à l'arrêt")
       print ("ventilateur activé")
       print ("circulateur à l'arrêt")
       GPIO.output(18,GPIO.LOW)
       GPIO.output(21,GPIO.LOW)
       GPIO.output(23,GPIO.LOW)
GPIO.cleanup()
```

Comment: It looks like the sensor is returning `None` for at least one of `temperature` or `humidity`. Try printing the values without formatting to see which it is, and then handle the value not being set.

Comment: I have this when I try it witout .format(temperature, humidity)   File "projet.py", line 18, in <module>
    if temperature > 25:
TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'NoneType' and 'int' I don't really understant what that means, I already tried to change the sign with => but it doesn't change anything

Answer (score 0):

The underlying library does not successfully read all the time. When it gives up it just returns None. Not a real problem though, you are reading it every 3 seconds, another chance is right around the corner.

You should only process the values once they are valid. You can do that like this:

```
while True:
    time.sleep(3),
    humidity, temperature  = Adafruit_DHT.read_retry(DHT_sensor, DHT_PIN)
    if temperature is not None and humidity is not None:
        print("Temp={0:0.1f}*C humidity={1:0.1f}%".format(temperature, humidity));
        if temperature > 25:
           print ("vanne ouverte")
           print ("boiler en fonctionnement")
           print ("ventilateur désactivé")
           print ("circulateur en fonctionnement")
           GPIO.output(18,GPIO.HIGH)
           GPIO.output(21,GPIO.HIGH)
           GPIO.output(23,GPIO.HIGH)
    
        else:
           print ("vanne fermée")
           print ("boiler à l'arrêt")
           print ("ventilateur activé")
           print ("circulateur à l'arrêt")
           GPIO.output(18,GPIO.LOW)
           GPIO.output(21,GPIO.LOW)
           GPIO.output(23,GPIO.LOW)
```

Then you can add more error handling like count up the errors in a row and if it ever gets too big do something more drastic.

Also you should do the same if you ever use humidity to test in a process. I have a sensor that reads humidity and temp and the humidity reading is always failing (30% of the time) but the reads still come in multiple times a minute.

Comment: it still doesn't work and print me the same error: print ("Temp={0:0.1f}*C humidity={1:0.1f}%".format(temperature, humidity));
TypeError: unsupported format string passed to NoneType.__format__                                                       do you have any other advice to fix it ?